# How to deploy to aws using sam to spesific stage and not affecting other stages?

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-sam, aws-sam-cli, sam

I want to be able to deploy to which stage I want without affecting other stages, for example, I want to deploy all the time to dev, and then deploy to prod without effect the dev stage

```
Resources:
  ApiGatewayApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
      StageName: Dev
      OpenApiVersion: "3.0"
      Name: asaf_api_second
      Description: "my api from sam"
```

if I change the StageName to Prod the stage Dev will delete, how can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

The required solution includes the following steps:

1. You will need to define the stage as a parameter in the root level:

   ```
   Parameters: 
     stage:
       Default: dev
       Description: StageName of API Gateway deployment
       Type: String

   Resources...
   ```
2. Add a reference using (!Ref) to the stage parameter name in the resource definition:

   ```
   Resources:
     ApiGatewayApi:
       Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
       Properties:
         EndpointConfiguration: REGIONAL
         StageName: !Ref stage
         OpenApiVersion: "3.0"
         Name: asaf_api_second
         Description: "my api from sam"
   ```
3. When you want to deploy to prod, override the required stage parameter in the deploy command using cli or in the toml file:

   ```
   sam deploy --parameter-overrides stage=prod
   ```